# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Item' 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Item>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

I have a view model that I build up using entity framework. The generated code brings back an ICollection of items from a Quote. However, I'm having trouble changing the viewmodel back into a model.

I want to retrieve an Item within a Quote.

```
public tQuote ToModel (QuoteViewModel quoteViewModel )
    {
        List<ItemViewModel> itemList = new List<ItemViewModel>();
        itemList.Add(quoteViewModel.Item); 

        return new tQuote()
        {
            QuotePK = quoteViewModel.QuoteID,
            QuoteNumber = quoteViewModel.QuoteReference,
            QuoteReqDate = quoteViewModel.QuoteReqDateTime,
            tItem = itemViewModelFactory.ToModel(itemList.FirstOrDefault())
        };
    }
```

I do not understand what I'm doing wrong. I have a list of Items, I add the first instance then select the first ItemViewModel.

Thanks for reading

**Edit** - As Requested

ItemViewModel:

```
public class ItemViewModel : DataViewModel
{
    public ItemViewModel()
    { }

    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public int? QuoteID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public QuoteViewModel Quote { get; set;}

}
```

tQuote:

```
public partial class tQuote
{
    public tQuote()
    {
        this.tItem = new HashSet<tItem>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<tItem> tItem { get; set; }
}
```

ItemViewModelFactory:

```
public class ItemViewModelFactory : IItemViewModelFactory
{
    private readonly IQuoteViewModelFactory quoteViewModelFactory; 

    public ItemViewModelFactory(IQuoteViewModelFactory quoteViewModelFactory)
    {
        this.quoteViewModelFactory = quoteViewModelFactory;
    }

    public ItemViewModel ToViewModel (tItem tItem)
    {
        return new ItemViewModel()
        {
            ItemID = tItem != null ? tItem.ItemPK : 0,
            QuoteID = tItem != null ? tItem.QuoteFK : 0,
            Title = tItem != null ? tItem.Title : "",
            Quote = tItem.tQuote != null ? quoteViewModelFactory.ToViewModel(tItem.tQuote) : new QuoteViewModel()
        };
    }

    public tItem ToModel (ItemViewModel itemViewModel )
    {
        return new tItem()
        {
            ItemPK = itemViewModel.ItemID,
            QuoteFK = itemViewModel.QuoteID,
            Title = itemViewModel.Title
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: ``itemList.FirstOrDefault()`` will reutrn ``Item`` type while ``tItem`` needs ``ICollection<Item>`` , can you show ``tQuote`` model and ``ItemViewModel`` class?

Comment: On which line you get this exception?

Comment: By error it is clear that you are returning List<T> , while actual return is having single value only i.e. T.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I've updated the original question.

Comment: @SonerGönül it's on tItem = itemViewModelFactory.ToModel(itemList.FirstOrDefault())

Comment: What does `itemViewModelFactory` do? Show us that class. Why do you create `itemList`, add one item to it and then do `itemList.FirstOrDefault()`? Why do your class names start with "t" (`tQuote`, `tItem`)? Why do you define `tItem` in `tQuote` as `ICollection<tItem>` but then instantiate it as `new HashSet<tItem>()` in the constructor?

Comment: @BCdotNET Hi, itemViewModelFactory has 2 methods, one for creating a view model and the other to create a (data) model. I create a itemList just to make an explicit conversion as this is related to your last question; the hashset is automatically generated by entity framework. Class names begin with a t because I'm converting some old data where all tables have t as a convention. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ToModel` in `ItemViewModelFactory` returns a `tItem`, but `tItem` in `tQuote` is actually an `ICollection<tItem>`.

I'd propose to rename `tItem` in `tQuote` to `tItems` so it becomes clear that it isn't a single item.

Also, in the method `public tQuote ToModel (QuoteViewModel quoteViewModel)` you'll need to change `tItem = itemViewModelFactory.ToModel(itemList.FirstOrDefault())` to `tItem = new new HashSet<tItem>{ itemViewModelFactory.ToModel(itemList.FirstOrDefault()) }`. And if I were you I'd change `itemList.FirstOrDefault()` to `quoteViewModel.Item` unless you do something else with `itemList` first.

Comment: You're right, I will pluralise the entities once I pass through this hurdle. Thanks

Comment: @DarkShadowAY Note that I've updated my answer; the first version was a quick placeholder.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to resolve the error but I found a better way in modelling the architecture. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Edited in light of further information in the comments.

The first version:

```
tItem = itemViewModelFactory.ToModel(itemList.FirstOrDefault())
```

is failing because the `ToModel` method returns a single `tItem` which of course is not implicitly convertible to `ICollection<tItem>`. You need to create a new collection object (one which implements `ICollection<tItem>`, such as `List<tItem>`) and pass this to `tItem`. For example:

```
tItem = new List<tItem>(itemViewModelFactory.ToModel(itemList.FirstOrDefault()))
```

The second version:

```
tItem = itemList
```

is failing because `tItem` is of type `ICollection<tItem>` whereas `itemList` is a `List<QuoteViewModel>`.
Although `List<T>` implements `ICollection<T>`, T of your `List<T>` does not equal T of your `ICollection<T>` so this is not a valid implicit cast.

On a side note: as others have pointed out your naming of types and members is rather unconventional and I suspect is at least in part driving your confusion. I'd suggest the information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a good source of help on this.

Also you do seem to be going about this in a rather convoluted fashion, but that wasn't the point of the question so I won't go further on that.

Comment: Hi, the return type is a new tItem that has an ID, ForeignKey ID, and a title